# Small ( < 15 megabytes) filesystem with basic android/dalvik framework

Tags: android, filesystems, root, dalvik

I try to create a very small partition (root filesystem) where I can run programs written in Java (android dalvik). Those applications will not use fancy functionality like telephone, multimedia, browser etc.
It will only run some services not using UI and use "basic" android things like intents, services, activities, binder aidl. I'm not interested in a JVM on a small linux distribution because this doesn't offer the basic android functionality like intents/services etc.
I intent to preinstall the applications as system applications on this filesystem. So no need to install them at a later time.

Is there a compile switch in the android platform build files to create such a "root filesystem"? Or is this doable with minimal effort (less than a few days of work)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your best bet is going to be the [porting](http://source.android.com/porting/index.html) section of the AOSP website.

It walks through the process of building and bringing up a custom Android system.